# ChartJS: Draw vertical line at data point on chart on mouseover

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I can't figure out how I might draw a vertical line on a line chart at a data point when hovering over it using Chart JS. I would like the line to stay within the bounds of the chart rectangle so that it does not extend into the tick area. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no native functionality for this yet, rather you would have to create a chart plugin to accomplish so.

**ᴘʟᴜɢɪɴ** (ᴅʀᴀᴡ ᴠᴇʀᴛɪᴄᴀʟ ʟɪɴᴇ ᴏɴ ᴍᴏᴜꜱᴇᴏᴠᴇʀ ᴀᴛ ᴅᴀᴛᴀ-ᴘᴏɪɴᴛ) :

```
Chart.plugins.register({
   afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
      if (chart.tooltip._active && chart.tooltip._active.length) {
         var activePoint = chart.tooltip._active[0],
             ctx = chart.ctx,
             y_axis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
             x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
             topY = y_axis.top,
             bottomY = y_axis.bottom;
         // draw line
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
         ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
         ctx.lineWidth = 2;
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#07C';
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      }
   }
});
```

<sup>* add this plugin at the beginning of your script</sup>

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ ⧩**

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
      if (chart.tooltip._active && chart.tooltip._active.length) {
         var activePoint = chart.tooltip._active[0],
            ctx = chart.ctx,
            y_axis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
            x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
            topY = y_axis.top,
            bottomY = y_axis.bottom;
         // draw line
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
         ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
         ctx.lineWidth = 2;
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#07C';
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      }
   }
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome. Can it also be done on click event as this is on hover / tooltip action?

Comment: thanks, this is awesome, everyone is trying to over complicate it but this is simple. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted a dashed line so I added `ctx.setLineDash([3, 3]);` after `ctx.beginPath();`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an accepted answer, I thought I might contribute a plugin I wrote which specifically addresses this question.

The chartjs line height annotation plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-lineheight-annotation

There are a few exportable classes which can help you calculate to the top of the datapoint if you need. Additionally, there is a simple API which you can add to your chart's options object

```
/// default values
lineHeightAnnotation: {
  // defaults to have line to the highest data point on every tick
  always: true,
  // optionally, only have line draw to the highest datapoint nearest the user's hover position
  hover: false,
  // colors of the line
  color: '#000',
  // name of yAxis
  yAxis: 'y-axis-0',
  // weight of the line
  lineWeight: 1.5,
   /// sets shadow for ALL lines on the canvas
  shadow: {
    // color of the shadow
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.35)',
    // blur of the shadow
    blur: 10,
    /// shadow offset
    offset: {
      // x offset
      x: 0,
      // y offset
      y: 3
    }
  },
  // dash defaults at [10, 10]
  noDash: true,
}
```